# interacting with a USB device in Golang

Tags: linux, go, usb, hardware

I am trying to communicate with a USB device ([cottonwood RFID reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0194MNAX8)) with golang under Linux.

Here is where I am so far:

1. My computer sees the hardware: I see the device in my `/dev/bus/usb`
2. The hardware works fine: the demo software they provide works seemlessly (under windows, they don't have a Linux version)
3. It seems I can open the endpoints
4. It seems I can write to the device

Now, when I try to read from thehardware, I always get a timeout. I'm a total beginner on hardware, any help would be greatly appreciated, maybe the issue is actually very basic.

My very simple codebase is here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/jpoirier/gousb/usb"
)

func main() {
    // Only one context should be needed for an application.  It should always be closed.
    ctx := usb.NewContext()
    defer func() {
        errCl := ctx.Close()
        if errCl != nil {
            log.Fatal(errCl)
        }
    }()

    ctx.Debug(1)

    // ListDevices is used to find the devices to open.
    devs, err := ctx.ListDevices(
        func(desc *usb.Descriptor) bool {
            if desc.Vendor == GetCottonwoodVendor() && desc.Product == GetCottonwoodProduct() {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })

    // All Devices returned from ListDevices must be closed.
    defer func() {
        for _, dev := range devs {
            errCl := dev.Close()
            if errCl != nil {
                log.Fatal(errCl)
            }
        }
    }()

    // ListDevices can occasionally  fail, so be sure to check its return value.
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("list: %s", err)
    }

for _, dev := range devs {
    // Once the device has been selected from ListDevices, it is opened
    // and can be interacted with.
    // Open up two ep for read and write

    epBulkWrite, err := dev.OpenEndpoint(1, 0, 0, 2|uint8(usb.ENDPOINT_DIR_OUT))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("OpenEndpoint Write error for %v: %v", dev.Address, err)
    }

    // Poll Firmware/Hardware Version ID

    // AntennaOn
    // outAntennaPowerOnCmd := []byte{0x18, 0x03, 0xFF}
    outFirmIdCmd := []byte{0x10, 0x03, 0x00}
    // outHardIdCmd := []byte{0x10, 0x03, 0x01}

    i, err := epBulkWrite.Write(outFirmIdCmd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot write command: %v\n", err)
    }
    log.Printf("%v bytes sent", i)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    epBulkRead, err := dev.OpenEndpoint(1, 0, 0, 1|uint8(usb.ENDPOINT_DIR_IN))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("OpenEndpoint Read error for %v: %v", dev.Address, err)
    }

    readBuffer := make([]byte, 64)
    n, errRead := epBulkRead.Read(readBuffer)
    log.Printf("read %d bytes: %v", n, readBuffer)
    if errRead != nil {
        log.Printf("error reading: %v", errRead)
        break
    }
}

// GetCottonwoodVendor returns the vendor ID of cottonwood UHF reader
func GetCottonwoodVendor() usb.ID {
    value, err := strconv.ParseUint("1325", 16, 16)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return usb.ID(value)
}

// GetCottonwoodProduct returns the product ID of cottonwood UHF reader
func GetCottonwoodProduct() usb.ID {
    value, err := strconv.ParseUint("c029", 16, 16)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return usb.ID(value)
}
```

First time I launch it, I get:

```
2016/12/14 19:19:18 3 bytes sent
2016/12/14 19:19:20 read 0 bytes: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
2016/12/14 19:19:20 error reading: libusb: timeout [code -7]
```

Second time and all after:

```
2016/12/14 19:21:21 Cannot write command: libusb: timeout [code -7]
```

I tried with another library using hidraw, but it seems not to work either (probably detach usb device issue).

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you run your program?

Comment: just added it!  

Basically, it can write, then can not read anything and then times out

Comment: I think the real problem is that you read zero bytes on the first run of the program.  If you can fix that, then the write timeout on the second run will probably go away.  I suspect the device is waiting for you to read the response to your command before it processes any more commands from you.  I am not sure why the read would fail.  Perhaps it is actually a non-blocking read?  Can you try delaying for, say, 100 ms before issuing the read?  What about doing a few reads in a row with 100 ms of delay between then?

Comment: I just added 1s sleep between the write and the read, but same issue. I also tried a loop read with 1s interval, always reads 0 byte.
I'm wondering if I should try to go towards HID libs to check if it works better. I will give it a try, I don't have many ideas left.